# Writing charcters in the csv files instead of writing the sentence

Tags: python, csv, data-science, jsonlines

I want to save my data in the CSV format, I have some sentences and I want to save every sentence in a different row, but the output is like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
with jsonlines.open('/content/data.jsonl') as reader:
    with open('/content/sample_data/sents.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      for obj in reader:
          if obj['label']=='ENOUGH':
              writer.writerow(obj['sent'])
```

and this is a piece of my data:

```
1 Cameroon lists three definitely endangered languages, 13 severely endangered, and 16 critically endangered from among its at least 250 languages.
2 Ryan Mathews of the 2003 Kansas State Wildcats football team posted a higher rushing average than his teammate Ell Roberson.
3 Alan Lowry only played games with his close relatives in his entire life.
```

I want to save them in differenet rows and a single column. what should I do?

Comment: Is this your data? It's not in jsonl format, I don't see any keys and values, just a string

Comment: The argument to `writerow()` should be a sequence of fields. You just gave a single string, so it's treated as a sequence of characters. Put it in a list.

Comment: @pbartkow I just wanted to show a sample of how my data looks like!!

Comment: @Barmar I stiil have the probelm, you mean this " writer.writerow(list(obj['claim']))"  right?

Comment: NO, `writer.writerow([obj['claim']])`

Comment: `list(thing)` turns the sequence in `thing` into a list of its elements. `[thing]` creates a list whose element is the value of `thing`.

Comment: @Barmar great thanks! but still they are in diffrent columns! every sentence breaks in smaller pieces and each piece appears in a diffrenet column!

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you have the correct number of `[]`

Comment: Why are you even using a CSV when there's just one field? Just use `csv_file.write(obj['sent'] + '\n')`

Comment: @Barmar I tried this out but I still had the problem finally I use pandas instead of CSV.

Answer (score -1):

I use pandas package for my purpose.
These are important links that I used: [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). I hope you find them useful too.